# Renaming Folder in wincvs

Tags: cvs, wincvs

I was having a folder named as 'subFolder' inside 'mainFolder' in wincvs.Now I decided to rename this folder as 'subfolder' to make all the letters in lower case.So I have deleted all the contents from the 'subFolder' folder and then I did a refresh to see 'subFolder' folder disappearing.Then I created new folder 'subfolder' inside 'mainFolder' folder and kept all the files which were there in old 'subFolder' folder inside that and added the folder and files into the repository.But now whenever I am checking out from CVS I am still getting the folder 'subFolder' instead of 'subfolder'.Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

CVS doesn't actually ever delete directories. It's really dumb. In order to see them "disappear", you need to turn on pruning during your updates. I'm not sure how to do this in WinCVS.

Answer (score 0):

if you copied the CVS hidden folder as well then the new 'subfolder' is connected to 'SubFloder'. it's kind of like in programming - you have 2 pointers to the same object.

try removing the folder again, then in the file explorer try deleting the hidden folder and the try adding 'subfolder' and files again - this will create a new (hidden) CVS folder. please note that this will also set all file revision back to 1.1.

hope this solves your problem